# Daily vote limit exceeded is ambiguous

Tags: feature-request, voting, comment-voting, popups

I recently saw my first "daily vote limit exceeded" limit after upvoting a comment.  It was not at all clear that it applied only to voting on comments.

I had read about voting on the site, and at no time did I come across any distinction between comment voting, question voting, and answer voting.  Therefore, I assumed I could not vote on anything else for the day.  (I even contemplated removing some comment upvotes so that I could upvote questions and answers.)

...and after I figured out that comment voting system was separate, I assumed voting on questions was, then, separate from voting on answers...but even later I (think I) found out that voting on questions and answers is a single system.

All of this confusion could be avoided by changing the pop-up message:

- "daily vote limit exceeded"

to

- "daily comment vote limit exceeded" in the case of comment voting, and
- "daily question-answer vote limit exceeded" in the case of question or answer voting.

Of course, if there are any other messages that are similarly ambiguous about which voting system they refer to, those could probably stand to be clarified too.

---

(Side note:  In posting this question found a "comment-voting" tag and a "voting" tag, but no "question-answer-voting" or "post-voting" tags.  I now understand that is because comment voting was implemented later, so for people who have been here since before that happened "voting" might to them mean voting on questions and answers, but now "voting" should really mean all voting...and there is room for a new tag for the voting subset that is not comment voting.  (I can add this as a new question if appropriate.  Just let me know.  :)  ))

Comment: Comment votes *aren't* a separate count from the question/answer votes.  You have 10 votes that can only be used on questions, and 40 votes that can be used on questions, answer, or comments.

Comment: This would be usefull if it really was ambiguous. It is already implemented. If you get the message when : Clicking on a comment, you've reached the comment limit. If it is while upvoting, you've reached the upvote limit.. If it is while downvoting, you've reached the downvote limit...

Comment: @Servy Comment votes are separate from question/answer votes. Check you vote count for the day, upvote a comment (this, for example), and check the vote count again (without voting on a question or answer in between).

Comment: @DanielFischer That comment votes don't increase that number don't mean that that number is identical to the daily vote cap.

Comment: @Servy True, that's only part of the proof. After that, go on up- and downvoting questions and answers until your daily vote count reaches 40 (if you vote on enough questions early enough, and don't vote on posts that will be deleted). And, for completeness, try voting on more than 40 (not-to-be-deleted) questions/answers on the next day, without voting on any comment.

Comment: @Servy INCORRECT.  I just confirmed this by going to a post and trying to upvote a comment (it was DENIED), trying to upvote the question (it was ACCEPTED), and trying to upvote an answer (it was ACCEPTED).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for pointing that out before I did.  I responded to Servy's comment as soon as I saw it because if left unchecked it would drag the question down.  I will leave my comment in place, though, just so that people are clear that this was tested.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd I quoted the exact pop-up message I saw.  Re-test exact message: "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 8 hours."  I am not sure what message you are talking about, but it is not the subject of my post.  What I have suggested has *not* already been implemented.